# Why does this Laravel5 ressource route 404?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In the file routes.php I added the line 
`Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');`
and then generated `TasksController` using artisan 
`php artisan make:controller TasksController`.

So why is `localhost/blog/public/tasks` returning 404?

Comment: You `TasksController` has the same function name inside it ?

Comment: It was generated with a number of methods inside it. I'm a beginner in Laravel so I just changed this : 

`    public function index()
    {
        return 'Hello Task';
        //
    }`

Comment: Is that the code inside your `TasksController` ?

Comment: yes, it was generated

Comment: But you should have this inside your TasksController `<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TasksController extends Controller {

 public function tasks()
 {
  return view('home');
 }

}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localhost/blog/public/index.php?tasks
```

You must pass all requests through /public/index.php
Best way to do this is set `DocumentRoot` to `/public/index.php/` and add entry to hosts file with simple domain eg. `laravel.app` mapped to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `mod_rewrite` enabled. You can read more at [Laravel installation guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2).

Also you need to point the root of your domain to /path/to/your/app/public and have the following .htacces there:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled in apache2